# Hyper-V licensing

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2016

I am an it consultant with 40+ years of experience but I am new to virtualization.  I have a host server with 2016 standard installed in a datacenter.  I used showkeyplus and the key shows as all B's most likely because it is their volume license.  I have read that 2016 standard allows 2 virtuals to be activated and that a physical windows 10 can connect to a virtual windows 10 license.  I have been able to create the virtual machines with no apparent issues.  My question is how do I activate the virtual machines so they don't expire?

Update:
I tried using key C3RCX-M6NRP-6CXC9-TW2F2-4RHYD (2016 standard) in the slmgr command and got the following error:

[image]

The slui command displayed:

[image]

Ideas?

Comment: Use an Automatic Virtual Machine Activation (AVMA) key to activate the guest https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started-19/vm-activation-19

Comment: See updates to initial question

Comment: AVMA keys require Datacenter edition. 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started-19/vm-activation-19
The following article should help activating Windows 10:
https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/124053-licensing-windows-10-with-virtualization-technologies-how-to
I would recommend you going with Windows Server as a VM OS and activate it with the host license key.